# Dashboard permission in WorkSpace

Tags: powerbi

I had created an App work-space, there is dashboard and a dataset inside.

If I add in some members inside, is there anyway that Do Not allow users to modify my dashboard while they still can use the dataset to build their own dashboard ?

Answer (score 0):

You can share the dashboard and limit the user for read or so re-share:

[Who has access to a dashboard or report you shared?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-share-dashboards#who-has-access-to-a-dashboard-or-report-you-shared)

However one of the limitations of the datasets is that "[No one can see or download the dataset.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-share-dashboards#limitations-and-considerations)"

Hope this can answer to your question. If not tell me please!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know how to share the dashboard and set the limitation to the users. However, I still wanna users can use the shared dataset to build their own dashboard without modifying my dashboard.